# using microsoft velocity / memcache from classic asp

Tags: performance, asp-classic, memcached, appfabric

How to read data from cache saved in microsoft velocity from classic asp?

If above is not possible, then what if I use memcache instead? Then is it possible and worth it to read memcache from classic asp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppFabric caching client libraries are .NET-only, you can't use them directly from ASP.

You *might* be able to get round this if you were to write a COM-visible object in .NET (a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), effectively) that you could instantiate in your ASP pages that would talk to the AppFabric cache.

Answer (score 2):

For memcached, I am looking in the following two examples below:

There is an enyim interop library that is available that looks like it will do the trick.  The site below has decent documentation on how to get it working:

https://github.com/enyim/membase-interop

Or take a look at the following article which links to a library you might be able to use:

https://vrobert.fr/2011/06/memcached-component-for-classic-asp/

http://drcarter.info/2011/06/memcached-component-for-classic-asp/ (dead)

Comment: The drcarter.info link is dead